# How to create a push segue from an existing tableview (not the initial view controller) to a TabBarController?

Tags: segue, tabbarcontroller

I have 4 tables organized hierarchically, from least detailed to most detailed: Table1 (higher level than 2) > Table2 (higher level than 3) > Table3 (higher level than 4) > Table4. Table1-3 are fully static. They do not change in components at all, so they were all hard coded through the storyboard. Now at table 4, the components may change, so I have managed through research and outside help to create and populate it programmatically.

Table4 has 2 sections with different number of rows. Say 2 rows in section 1 and 3 rows in 2. Now what I want to do is everytime the user click one of the cells in any rows, irrespective of sections, he/she is taken to the tabbarcontroller I currently designed on the storyboard. This tab bar has 2 tabs. The 1st tab when pushed should show general information about the component at the row just clicked on. The 2nd should show a bunch of statistics on that same component which row was clicked.

That is it. That is what I the end product should be able to do. I am currently stuck at how to create the segue from this table that is created programmatically (table4). In sort, this segue should be dynamic in the sense that irrespective of the row clicked, you are always taken to the same view (the tab bar).

I am happy to to work through this on my own if I can find some a good book or source on the internet that shows how to set this up from where I am today in the project. But I have searched and have failed to come up with anything.

Comment: As I know, apple don't let you using tabbar inside a navigation controller. Maybe you should use the SegmentControl

Comment: I see. OK I will research to see how they work and are setup. However, I still need to create a segue that will go from my table4 to the segment control page should I decided to go that route. Any idea on how to do this or where I can find an example?